# LaunchEffect cause issue to trigger when value changes in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change the ui on button click so I am using ui event. I tried some code and it's working fine. I want to check some variable value so I created a `LaunchEffect` to trigger and print the value in log. After using `LaunchEffect` my view is not changing anymore i.e. it stucks on same screen. I have one screen where I am using `HorizontalPager` and other screen just printing the value in `Text`.

**SaveVariable**

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
fun SaveVariable() {
    val viewModel = VariableViewModel()
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = pagerState) {
        snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
            viewModel.currentIndex = page
        }
    }
//    this code is causing issue
//    LaunchedEffect(key1 = viewModel.setLastCurrentPage) {
//        Log.e(">> LaunchedEffect", "${viewModel.currentIndex}")
//    }
    LgcTheme {
        SaveVariableItem(viewModel.currentIndex, viewModel.uiState, pagerState) {
            viewModel.changeUIi()
            viewModel.setLastCurrentPage = true
        }
    }
}
```

**VariableViewModel**

```
class VariableViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var uiState by mutableStateOf(ScreenName.FIRST)
    var setLastCurrentPage by mutableStateOf(false)
    var currentIndex by mutableStateOf(0)
    fun changeUIi() {
        uiState = if (uiState == ScreenName.FIRST) {
            ScreenName.SECOND
        } else {
            ScreenName.FIRST
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenName**

```
enum class ScreenName {
    FIRST,
    SECOND
}
```

**SaveVariableItem**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun SaveVariableItem(
    currentIndex: Int,
    uiState: ScreenName,
    pagerState: PagerState,
    changeUiState: () -> Unit,
) {
    Column {
        when (uiState) {
            ScreenName.FIRST -> {
                ScreenFirstView(pagerState)
            }

            ScreenName.SECOND -> {
                ScreenSecondView(currentIndex, "SECOND")
            }
        }
        Button(onClick = { changeUiState() }) {
            Text(text = "Add")
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenFirstView**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ScreenFirstView(pagerState: PagerState) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .background(Color.Black)
    ) {
        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp),
            pageCount = 10,
            state = pagerState
        ) { page ->
            Text(
                text = "Page: $page",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                color = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenSecondView**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenSecondView(currentIndex: Int, screenImage: String) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .background(Color.Black)
    ) {
        Text(text = "$currentIndex ==== $screenImage", color = Color.White)
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this piece of code is causing issue to unable to change the ui code

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = viewModel.setLastCurrentPage) {
    Log.e(">> LaunchedEffect", "${viewModel.currentIndex}")
}
```

Please guide me what I am doing wrong in here. Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to move

```
 viewModel.setLastCurrentPage = true
```

into viewmodel function called `changeUIi()` something like this

```
    fun changeUIi() {
        uiState = if (uiState == ScreenName.FIRST) {
            setLastCurrentPage = false
            ScreenName.SECOND
        } else {
            setLastCurrentPage = true
            ScreenName.FIRST
        }
    }
```

my view change but `LaunchEffect` doesn't trigger to print logs.

Comment: Here I can see that ```LaunchedEffect``` will trigger only once then ```viewModel.setLastCurrentPage``` value remains same so It will not update The State.

Comment: I updated my code, I moved the value into viewmodel and after my LauncEffect its not working correctly.

Comment: @KotlinLearner could you provide a github repo so we can clone your project and see whats wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem i see is that you are recreating `viewModel` on each recomposition, you should obtain it like this:

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    fun SaveVariable(viewModel: VariableViewModel = viewModel()) {
    ...
```

Comment: I tried but not not working correctly..

Comment: That's weird, it wasn't working for me at all until i deleted `val viewModel = VariableViewModel()` and added the code in my answer. The only other thing i changed is that i deleted deprecated `pageCount = 10,` from the pager in `ScreenFirstView` and moved it into `val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { 10 })` in `SaveVariable` composable. Either way, directly creating view model in a composable is an incorrect way, it will be recreated on each recomposition of the `SaveVariable`,

Comment: So what do you suggest to fix the problem? I changed your way of doing in viewmodel but nothing working and I don't understand..

Comment: @KotlinLearner There must be some subtle differences, but it is difficult to say. As another commenter suggested you could share a not working project on github.

Comment: Yeah it works on my side.

Answer (score -1):

Use delay inside **LaunchedEffect**

**delay(5000)**

**Changed Code:**

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = viewModel.setLastCurrentPage) {
          delay(5000)
          Log.e(">> LaunchedEffect", "${viewModel.currentIndex}")
}
```

Comment: I cannot use slow delay in my code. I want to show update immediately to the user.